# iReports 4.5.1 Sub Reports Display only in the last page with not page numbers in the footer

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

How do I display a sub report (actually two) only in the last page of my report.  At the same time I don't want the parent reports header and footer informations displayed in that last page where I am displaying my sub reports.

I am using:

iReport 4.5.1 as my report designer and  Oracle 11g/Stored procedures that returns a ref cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the two subreports on the summary band and then in the report properties make sure you check the 'Summary on a new page' field and uncheck the 'Summary with page header and footer' field.

Comment: I tried as you suggested and it worked fine... is there a way to dynamically increase the summary band based on the sub report's out put... As my first sub report is sort of overlapping with the second one.... Again Thanks a bunch for a quick response....

Comment: Subreports are tricky when it comes to sizing. What I would recommend is editing your subreport to be as small and tight-fit as possible. Also, I'm not sure if this will help/work but in your summary band's properties tab there is a "split type" attribute. Maybe changing that will solve the overlapping issue. I wish I could be more help regarding that.

Comment: Hi Precose,  Thanks again for a quick response.  I tried editing my sub report as you suggested and even then my two sub reports in the summary band overlaps.  Also iReports 4.5.1 I am not able to change the Split Type property it always defaults to <default> in the drop down.
1. Is there a way to add another summary band like how you can add another reglar dabase field base group.

Comment: I've got a good idea that should work. On your mainreport click on the bottom-most subreport and in it's properties tab change the attribute "position type" to "fix relative to bottom"

Comment: Hi Precose,  Thanks again... yes I tried the Position Type of the last sub Report to Fix Relative to Bottom when I previewed it my last sub report completely vanished (its not showing up at all)... I am new to Jasper/iReports and I am figuring things out by trial and error

Comment: Ok If I set the property of the last sub report to floating it worked.... Thaks a bunch Precose...I have been breaking my head on this for the past two days....HAVE A GREAT WK END....

Comment: Glad you could figure it out! You have a great weekend as well!